# I take "Timed out waiting to connect to the MySql server. Please check if your connection settings are..." Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

When I try to connect MySQL server, I encounter "Timed out waiting to connect to the MySql server. Please check if your connection settings are correct, and also see if the server is running correctly and then try to connect".  The server is running but I do not understand the problem. I also added library MySQL connector/J.

Comment: Either the server or the connection settings are misconfigured most likely. Hard to tell without knowing the details. There isn't much to do here apart from double-checking the configurations and narrowing down the issue.